# How to write a proxy-server in Python?

Tags: python, proxy

(Edited to note: exact duplicate of 989739)

Could you give any suggestions or online sourses as to the matter of writing one's own client proxy-server? In particular, this proxy must be able to make one thing: replace the HTTP-headers sent by browsers with my own ones.